# How to filter by price range in sample cube of kylin

Tags: kylin

Sorry, I just start to lean kylin

When I execute the sql `select * from kylin_sales where price > 2` in default sample cube of kylin, it failed with the message

```
ERROR while executing SQL "select * from kylin_sales where price > 2 LIMIT 50000": Can't find any realization. Please confirm with providers SQL digest: fact table DEFAULT.KYLIN_SALES,group by [],filter on[DEFAULT.KYLIN_SALES.PRICE],with aggregates[].
```

anybody knows the reason? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kylin is a [MOLAP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhFkNmVmwn4) (multidimensional online analytical processing) engine. It divides columns into dimensions and measures, expects queries to filter by dimensions and return aggregated measures.

Your query `select * from kylin_sales where price > 2` does not work, because `price` is not a dimension thus is not suitable for filtering. Also the query does not select any aggregated measures.

A simple MOLAP query is like `select week_beg_dt, sum(price) from kylin_sales where meta_categ_name='Collectibles' group by week_beg_dt`

Kylin also supports a special type of `RAW` measure, that allows filter such as `price > 2`, but that's not demonstrated by the sample cube.